# UITableView indexPath and maximum number of reusable cells

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, core-data

My `UITableView` with custom reusable cells is done but two issues remain:

1. I can create 6 cells but when I add the 7th the app crashes with `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` which I really can not understand. The `view` crashes again instantly when I relaunch the app.
2. The cells' data is reused correctly except for the `valueLabel.text`'s. **When I update this value on a cell with the `tableView` scrolled, the data falls back one row** (as illustrated). I believe this is an `indexPath` problem related to incorrect editing (updating?) of the `data source` but **when I relaunch the app the data is in the correct cell.**

[image]

I marked these events 1 and 2 in the code below.

**Creating the data:**

```
func createCryptoArray(_ addedCrypto: String) {

        if addedCrypto == "Bitcoin BTC" {
            if CoreDataHandler.saveObject(name: "Bitcoin", code: "bitcoin", symbol: "BTC", placeholder: "BTC Amount", amount: "0.00000000", amountValue: "0.0") {
                for _ in CDHandler.fetchObject()! {
                }
            }
        }
        if addedCrypto == "Bitcoin Cash BCH" {
            if CoreDataHandler.saveObject(name: "Bitcoin Cash", code: "bitcoinCash", symbol: "BCH", placeholder: "BCH Amount", amount: "0.00000000", amountValue: "0.0") {
                for _ in CDHandler.fetchObject()! {
                }
            }
        } 
        //...
    }
}
```

**WalletTableViewController:** (with problem 1)

```
class WalletTableViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var cryptos : [CryptosMO] = []

var total : Double = 0.0
static var staticTotal : Double = 0.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    if CDHandler.fetchObject() != nil {
        cryptos = CDHandler.fetchObject()!
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    update()

    updateWalletValue()
    updateWalletLabel()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    update()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    if CDHandler.fetchObject() != nil {
        cryptos = CDHandler.fetchObject()!
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func updateCellValue() {

    for section in 0...self.tableView.numberOfSections - 1 {
        if (self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) >= 1) {
            for row in 0...self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) - 1 {
                let indexP: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section);
                self.updateCellValueLabel(self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexP) as! WalletTableViewCell) // <-------Problem 1
            }
        }
    }
}

func update() {

    updateCellValue()
}
}
```

**TableView functions:**

```
extension WalletTableViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CryptoCellDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cryptos.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! WalletTableViewCell

    cell.cryptoNameLabel.text = cryptos[indexPath.row].name
    cell.cryptoCodeLabel.text = cryptos[indexPath.row].symbol
    cell.amountLabel.text = cryptos[indexPath.row].amount
    cell.amountTextField.placeholder = cryptos[indexPath.row].placeholder

    if cryptos[indexPath.row].amountValue == "0.0" {
        cell.cryptoValueLabel.text = ""
    }

    cell.delegate = self
    cell.amountTextField.delegate = self

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let selectedManagedObject = cryptos[indexPath.row]
        CDHandler.deleteObject(entity:"CryptosMO", deleteObject: selectedManagedObject)
        cryptos.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        updateWalletValue()
        updateWalletLabel()
    }
}
```

**User Action, calculations and data update:** (with `valueLabel.text's`)

```
// TextFields amounts
//--------------------
func cellAmountEntered(_ walletTableViewCell: WalletTableViewCell) {

    if walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text == "" {
        return
    }

    let str = walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    let dNumber = formatter.number(from: str!)
    let nDouble = dNumber!
    let eNumber = Double(truncating: nDouble)
    walletTableViewCell.amountLabel.text = String(format:"%.8f", eNumber)

    var editAmount = ""
    editAmount = String(format:"%.8f", eNumber)

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: walletTableViewCell)
    let selectedManagedObject = cryptos[(indexPath?.row)!]

    CDHandler.editObject(editObject: selectedManagedObject, amount: editAmount, amountValue: "0.0")

    walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text = ""

}

// Value calculation & label update
//----------------------------------
func updateCellValueLabel(_ walletTableViewCell: WalletTableViewCell) {

    if walletTableViewCell.amountLabel.text == "" {
        walletTableViewCell.amountLabel.text = "0.00000000"
    }

    var newCryptos : [CryptosMO] = []
    var doubleAmount = 0.0

    var cryptoPrice = ""
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: walletTableViewCell)

    if CDHandler.fetchObject() != nil {
        newCryptos = CDHandler.fetchObject()!
    }

    cryptoPrice = cryptos[(indexPath?.row)!].code!
    guard let cryptoDoublePrice = CryptoInfo.cryptoPriceDic[cryptoPrice] else { return }

    let selectedAmount = newCryptos[(indexPath?.row)!]

    guard let amount = selectedAmount.amount else { return }
    var currentAmountValue = selectedAmount.amountValue

    doubleAmount = Double(amount)!

    let calculation = cryptoDoublePrice * doubleAmount
    currentAmountValue = String(calculation)

    CoreDataHandler.editObject(editObject: selectedAmount, amount: amount, amountValue: currentAmountValue)

    walletTableViewCell.valueLabel.text = String(calculation) // <-------- `valueLabel.text`
}
```

}

**CoreData functions:**

```
class CoreDataHandler: NSObject {

class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
}

class func saveObject(name:String, code:String, symbol:String, placeholder:String, amount:String, amountValue:String) -> Bool {
    let context = getContext()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "CryptosMO", in: context)
    let managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

    managedObject.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
    managedObject.setValue(code, forKey: "code")
    managedObject.setValue(symbol, forKey: "symbol")
    managedObject.setValue(placeholder, forKey: "placeholder")
    managedObject.setValue(amount, forKey: "amount")
    managedObject.setValue(amountValue, forKey: "amountValue")

    do {
        try context.save()
        return true
    } catch {
        return false
    }
}

class func fetchObject() -> [CryptosMO]? {
    let context = getContext()
    var cryptos: [CryptosMO]? = nil

    do {
        cryptos = try context.fetch(CryptosMO.fetchRequest()) as? [CryptosMO]
        return cryptos
    } catch {
        return cryptos
    }
}

class func deleteObject(entity: String, deleteObject: NSManagedObject) {
    let context = getContext()
    context.delete(deleteObject)

    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}

class func editObject(editObject: NSManagedObject, amount: String, amountValue: String) {
    let context = getContext()
    let managedObject = editObject

    do {
        managedObject.setValue(amount, forKey: "amount")
        managedObject.setValue(amountValue, forKey: "amountValue")
        try context.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}

}
```

Comment: `self.tableView.cellForRow(at:)` returns nil if the cell is not visible. And since you do an unwrap there with "!", that explains the crash.

Comment: You should remove `updateCellValue()`. `UITableView`automatically calls `tableView(_, cellForRowAt:)` **when it needs it**, you just need to update your info array and call `tableView.reloadData()`. The table view will automatically use that method when it needs it **for visible cells**. It's a passive way, it's a **delegate**.

Comment: @AlejandroIván Where and how do I update my info array?

Comment: @martin your `cryptos` array. I was referring to the array you use to fill the table view.

Comment: @Larme in `tableView.cellForRow(at:)` or `updateCellValue()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are using the UIKit framework completely *inverse* to how it is intended: Your code loops through your data model and wants to update each and every cell in the table view. Imaging you have thousands of rows, then you would (at least) try to update tousands of cells. But, as @Larme already mentioned, those cells do not exist (since they are not visible), and most of your calls are in vain.

To use UIKit correctly, you must change your approach: You do not update actively, but instead you will be called by the table view if the table view detects that it has to display data in a cell (or in multiple cells, each one after the other), because the view got visible, the user scrolled etc. So if the table view only displays 5 cells, it only asks for the data of 5 cells, and not for the whole database.

What you'll have to do is:

- remove `func updateCellValue()`. If you think you'll have to update the view, call `reloadData()` or `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths...` at the table view. This will result in calling the appropriate data source methods, like...
- at the end of `tableView(cellForRowAt:)`, you call `updateCellValueLabel` with the dequeued cell, which then will update the label.
- You should also modify `updateCellValueLabel` and hand in the `IndexPath` (or only the row), so you do not need to call `tableView.indexPath(for: walletTableViewCell)` any more.

This is just a simple hint of what to do; you also might think of optimizing the data fetching

---

**Addition** regarding the third point (see comment):
You could modify your code in the following way:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // ... same as before

    cell.delegate = self
    cell.amountTextField.delegate = self

    updateCellValueLabel(cell, atRow:indexPath.row)
    return cell
}

func updateCellValueLabel(_ walletTableViewCell: WalletTableViewCell, atRow row:Int) {

    if walletTableViewCell.amountLabel.text == "" {
        walletTableViewCell.amountLabel.text = "0.00000000"
    }

    var newCryptos : [CryptosMO] = []
    var doubleAmount = 0.0

    var cryptoPrice = ""

    if CDHandler.fetchObject() != nil {
        newCryptos = CDHandler.fetchObject()!
    }

    cryptoPrice = cryptos[row].code!
    guard let cryptoDoublePrice = CryptoInfo.cryptoPriceDic[cryptoPrice] else { return }

    let selectedAmount = newCryptos[row]

    guard let amount = selectedAmount.amount else { return }
    var currentAmountValue = selectedAmount.amountValue

    doubleAmount = Double(amount)!

    let calculation = cryptoDoublePrice * doubleAmount
    currentAmountValue = String(calculation)

    CoreDataHandler.editObject(editObject: selectedAmount, amount: amount, amountValue: currentAmountValue)

    walletTableViewCell.valueLabel.text = String(calculation) // <-------- `valueLabel.text`
}
```

So `updateCellValueLabel` gets an extra `atRow` parameter, to access the correct value in the `cryptos` and `newCryptos` arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much Andreas, this seems to be the perfect answer! There are a few things I don't fully understand tho. I've been learning `tableViews` and `CoreData` at the same time this week, sorry about that. I got your second point correctly but could you add a little more precisions to the other two? Especially `hand in the IndexPath (or only the row), so you do not need to call tableView.indexPath`. Thanks again!

Comment: It works perfectly Andreas! Two more questions: How can I pass `indexPath.row` from another class when calling `updateCellValueLabel` through delegate? What would you advise me to read to better understand the `tableView` logic? Thanks again :)

Comment: To understand the stuff, you could visit a developer training or check some online trainings like from stanford university - just search for "cs193p" on youtube, there is also a video about table views.
I don't quite understand the first question, please be more precise -- indexPath.row is the index in your data model which is being displayed in the cell.

Comment: I'll check these out! Yeah I forgot that idea and simply called `tableView.reloadData()` from `cellAmountEntered()` so table will call `updateCellValueLabel()` itself

Answer (score 0):

The real problem lies in your logic of updating the cells. You use a function called `updateCellValue()` which is meant to force-update the cells “from outside”. This is wrong. Rather, you would update your datasource and have the tableView pull these changes by invoking `self.tableView.reloadData()`. Never update a table view by updating its cells but have the table view update itself by simply updating the datasource.